# ERROR TypeError: this.registeredUserArray.some is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to store registered user object inside localstorage, but when I try to get or set those values from localstorage in an array even though I parse it back to object it gives error .push or .some is not a function

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cart } from 'src/app/models/cart';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { productAndQuantity } from 'src/app/models/product-and-quantity';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  registeredUserArray : User[];
  tempCart: Cart = new Cart;
  purchaseHistoryCartArray: Cart[] = [];
  localStorageKey = "registeredUserArray";


  defaultUsers : User[] = [
    {
      username : "gss@google.com",
      password : "BruceWayne@123",
      isAdmin : true,
    },
    {
      username : "test@gmail.com",
      password : "BruceWayne@123",
      isAdmin : false,
      tempCart: new Cart,
      purchaseHistoryCartArray: []
    },
  ]

  constructor() {

    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey)!))
    {
      this.registeredUserArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey)! ?? []);
    }
    else 
    {
      this.registeredUserArray = this.defaultUsers;
      localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(this.defaultUsers));
    }
  }

  addUser(user : User)
  {
    // this.registeredUserArray.push(user); 
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey)!))
    this.registeredUserArray.push(user); **<--this is the point of error**
    localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(this.registeredUserArray));
  }
```

Comment: Please share the result of `console.log(this.registeredUserArray)` at the point just before you get the error.

Comment: when I log  in addUser
```console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey)!))
    console.log("log from addUser: " +this.registeredUserArray```
it gives : 
```{purchaseHistoryCartArray: Array(0), username: 'walter@white.com', password: 'JEssie@123', isAdmin: false, tempCart: {…}}
log from addUser: [object Object]```

Comment: Which is an object, not an array

Comment: It is supposed to be array of object named User

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cart } from 'src/app/models/cart';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { productAndQuantity } from 'src/app/models/product-and-quantity';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  registeredUserArray: User[];
  tempCart: Cart = new Cart();
  purchaseHistoryCartArray: Cart[] = [];
  localStorageKey = "registeredUserArray";

  constructor() {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey);

    if (storedData) {
      this.registeredUserArray = JSON.parse(storedData);
    } else {
      this.registeredUserArray = this.defaultUsers;
      localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(this.defaultUsers));
    }
  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    this.registeredUserArray.push(user);
    localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(this.registeredUserArray));
  }

  // ... other methods ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the handler:**

```js
constructor() {
  this.localStorageHandler(this.localStorageKey,this.defaultUsers);
}

//helper function

public localStorageHandler(key:string, dataToStore) {
 const localStoreData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key);
  if (localStoreData && Array.isArray(localStoreData))
    {
      this.registeredUserArray = localStoreData;
      return;
    }
    this.registeredUserArray = dataToStore;
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(this.defaultUsers));
}
```